# SwiftUI: SpriteView completely redraws when model changes

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit

I'm creating simple game using SwiftUI and SpriteKit. I pass model as parameter to GameScene and the problem is that when the model changes parameter that makes Text View in VStack to redraw itself (in my case it's viewModel.model.currentProgress). SpriteView completely redraws as well

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = viewModel()

    var scene: GameScene {
        let scene = GameScene(model: $viewModel.model)
        scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        
        return scene
      }
    

      var body: some View {
          
              VStack{
                  
                  Text("Winning cond: \(String(describing: viewModel.model.conditions))")
                  Text("Current progress: \(String(describing: viewModel.model.currentProgress))")
                  
                  SpriteView(scene: scene)
                     .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                     .ignoresSafeArea()

          }
      }
    
}
```

Is there any way to change that behaviour?

Comment: SwiftUI doesn't "draw" anything, it works by creating and diffing these View structs which is negligible performance-wise. Only if there is a difference is anything actually drawn (much further down the stack). Remove the view model object and learn how the View struct works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern you can try for sharing a model between SwiftUI and SpriteKit, while avoiding the redraw problem:

- instantiate your Model in global scope; pass it to SwiftUI as an environmentObject
- instantiate your GameScene as a variable in SwiftUI

**SwiftUI entry point**

```
//create Model in global scope
let model = Model()

@main
struct Main: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(model) //pass Model into environment
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model:Model //receive Model from environment
    var gameScene:GameScene = GameScene() //create GameScene instance
        
    var body: some View {
        [...]
        SpriteView(scene: gameScene)
        [...]
    }
}
```

this way, SwiftUI can communicate to the Model and to GameScene directly (since it holds the former as an environment object, and the latter as a normal variable reference). and GameScene can communicate back with the Model since the model is a globally scoped variable -- and hence GameScene can also communicate w/ SwiftUI indirectly by changing values in the model.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It worked. As you suggested, I instantiated my ViewModel (in global scope), I couldn't do it with Model because, in my case, Model is a struct. So I put Model inside ViewModel. SwiftUI updates perfectly well any Views associated with variables in ViewModel but it won't update anything associated with my Model. I can't figure out why. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: can you simply merge your Model and ViewModel? sometimes a flatter hierarchy helps. it's also possible to use the delegate pattern: give your Model a (weak) reference back to the ViewModel; then when certain things change in the Model, use the delegate reference to inform the ViewModel (which updates its @Published properties, thereby updating your View).

Comment: I can't thank you enough! Delegate pattern works great and although it's now the same as I planned (where my model is the only source of truth and viewModel translates certain changes to View), it's still works which is awesome. I thought that I would have to give up the project. Thanks again